# Multiple rows deletion in HBase using Shell Script

Tags: shell, hbase

I need to have a shell script which deletes multiple HBase rows based on the row keys.

I tried to delete multiple rows in a HBase table using rowkeys. However the script I am using is deleting rows one by one every time logging into the HBase shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a rowkeys=("1" "2")
table="ns:my_table"
echo $table
for rowkey in "${rowkeys[@]}"
do
echo -e "deleteall '$table' , '$rowkey' "  | hbase shell
done
```

Below is the output I am getting:
But I need only s single HBase shell login and delete the rows.

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
19/06/24 04:32:56 INFO Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.2.0-cdh5.16.1, rUnknown, Wed Nov 21 21:51:49 PST 2018

deleteall 'ns:my_table' , '1'
0 row(s) in 0.4510 seconds

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
19/06/24 04:33:01 INFO Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.2.0-cdh5.16.1, rUnknown, Wed Nov 21 21:51:49 PST 2018

deleteall 'ns:my_table' , '2'
0 row(s) in 0.3800 seconds

Comment: Please reformat your post. Please explain what you do and how you do it. Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Anyway, so, what is your problem?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, Thanks for the response. I will make sure to reformat. My problem here is when I try to execute the script I posted, it everytime logs in to HBase shell then deletes a single row. But it needs to login to HBase shell once, then perform multiple deletes.

Comment: Build up a big string with new lines between each argument, then pipe that into HBase shell.

Comment: Thanks @BenWatson. It helps. Modified the code as : 
declare -a rowkeys=("1" "2")
    table="ns:my_table"
    echo $table
    for rowkey in "${rowkeys[@]}"
    do
    str="$str ; deleteall '$table' , '$rowkey'"
    done
    echo $str | hbase shell

 Is there any way that I can put a sleep interval of 1s for every 100 rows deletion ?